# Recursive SELECT Query

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship, recursive-query

I got this database with this query:
https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=fc20b8c06475c031940c1654a50ff1fa&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80

The result of the query is this one:

```
   "menu": [
      {
        "Colazione": {
          "items": {
            "Colazione": [
              {
                "item_name": "Cornetto"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Pranzo": {
          "items": {
            "Primi piatti": [
              {
                "item_name": "Pasta al sugo"
              },
              {
                "item_name": "Pasta al sugo n.2"
              },
              {
                "item_name": "Pasta al sugo n.3"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

I want to edit it in this way:
As you can see, the database got Category, Sub-Categories and Items.
Into the "JSON" the key "Colazione" is only a category that doesn't got any sub-category (parent_id is NULL), then I want that it print directly the items without printing x2 times "Colazione" like a sub-categories.

The expected result should be this one:

```
   "menu": [
      {
        "Colazione": {
          "items": [
              {
                "item_name": "Cornetto"
              }
            ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Pranzo": {
          "items": {
            "Primi piatti": [
              {
                "item_name": "Pasta al sugo"
              },
              {
                "item_name": "Pasta al sugo n.2"
              },
              {
                "item_name": "Pasta al sugo n.3"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

In the expected JSON we got: "Colazione" that is only a category with items and "Pranzo" that is a category with sub-categories like "Primi Piatti" with multiple items

Comment: Why does the `phpize`code not contain "Colazione" ? ( id mean the example that you are questioning about, is not in your sample database on `phpize`).

Comment: Its Breakfast, I update it right now :)